# How to send Google drive token stored as json string(in database) in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync method in .Net?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am converting Google token in json string format and storing that string in database.

Now while uploading files in google drive, I want to send that json in **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** method to get credentials which used to get DriveService.

So I can create a background task which checks the token and uploads files automatically without user interaction.
Also I can use that credential to create new json file and save in Database so that if the access token is updated it can be store automatically.

```
UserCredential credential;    

credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = "",
                            ClientSecret = ""
                        },
                        new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                        Page.User.Identity.Name,
                        CancellationToken.None).Result;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credential.Token);

var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Test",
            });
```

Am I doing right thing ? Or is there any other way to save the credential in database rather then saving in file ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i understand you correctly you are saving the refresh token to the database and want to use this later to access the api.

Whate you should be doing is storing the refresh token only then creating your own implementation of idatastore to load it.  Currently you are using filedatastore which is going to look for it in the file stored in %appdata%

I have a bunch of examples here [database datastores](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf)  but here is the one for entity framework since you havent said which database you are using.

```
using Google.Apis.Json;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleAuthDataStores
{
    public class GoogleUserCredential
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required, Index(IsUnique = true), StringLength(500)]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Credentials { get; set; }
    }

    internal class EntityFrameworkDataStore : DbContext, IDataStore
    {
        public DbSet<GoogleUserCredential> GoogleUserCredentials { get; set; }

        /// <summary>The string used to open the connection.</summary>
        public virtual string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new table in the data base if the Users table does not exist within the database used in the connectionstring.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString">The string used to open the connection.</param>
        public EntityFrameworkDataStore(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the given value for the given key. It creates a new row in the database with the user id of
        /// (primary key <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>) in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to store in the data store.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to store in the data store.</param>
        Task IDataStore.StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
            }

            var serialized = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Serialize(value);
            save(GenerateStoredKey(key), serialized);
            return Task.Delay(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the given key. It deletes the <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/> row in
        /// <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key to delete from the data store.</param>
        Task IDataStore.DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
            }

            try
            {
                var hold = GoogleUserCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
                GoogleUserCredentials.Remove(hold);
                SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to delete credentials", ex);
            }

            return Task.Delay(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the stored value for the given key or <c>null</c> if the matching row (<see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>
        /// in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/> doesn't exist.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to retrieve.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">The key to retrieve from the data store.</param>
        /// <returns>The stored object.</returns>
        Task<T> IDataStore.GetAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
            }

            TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
            var user = GetUserByKey(GenerateStoredKey(key));
            if (user != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<T>(user.Credentials));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(default(T));
            }
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears all values in the data store. This method deletes all files in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
        /// </summary>
        Task IDataStore.ClearAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in GoogleUserCredentials)
                {
                    GoogleUserCredentials.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to clear credentials", ex);
            }

            return Task.Delay(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the user exists <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private GoogleUserCredential GetUserByKey(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = GoogleUserCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user != null)
                    return user;

                return null;
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the credentials.  If the user <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/> does not exists we insert it other wise we will do an update.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="serialized"></param>
        private void save(string key, string serialized)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = GoogleUserCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    var hold = new GoogleUserCredential { Key = key, Credentials = serialized };
                    GoogleUserCredentials.Add(hold);
                }
                else
                {
                    var aUser = this.GoogleUserCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
                    aUser.Credentials = serialized;
                }
                SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Creates a unique stored key based on the key and the current project name.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The object key.</param>
        public static string GenerateStoredKey(string key)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name, key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am saving token data in SQL. And converted whole token data into json object and saving that json object as string in SQL database.

Comment: check this one https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf#file-sqlserverdatabase-cs  it will be much easer.

Comment: So in that I need to write my own SQL command at "LINE 37". Right ?
Sorry for asking much but I am new to this thing. So want to clarify before messing up.

Comment: you are going to have to test it if you check the dates I wrote those a while ago.    They worked at the time.  I can try to find some time to write up a tutorial over the weekend