# Save user credentials to database with Google Web Authorization Broker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have successfully user the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` to save user credentials to a file. But I want my app to be a little more secure. So I am trying to save the credentials to my my sqlite database. I have followed some information from this Stack overflow Post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045751/how-to-send-google-drive-token-stored-as-json-stringin-database-in-googlewebau) I have made the Entity Framework class but now Im unsure on how to use it to save the data to the database. This is my Current code

```
return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    _scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    GoogleCredentialsDataStore.GenerateStoredKey("What string value goes here")
```

So Im a little lost on what string value goes into the GenerateStoredKey parameter so that it will process and save to my database.

this is the Data interface part of the project .

```
public class GoogleCredentialsDataStore : SqLiteDbContext, IDataStore
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Database context to access database
        /// </summary>
        private readonly SqLiteDbContext _context;
        public GoogleCredentialsDataStore(SqLiteDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stores the given value for the given key. It creates a new row in the database with the user id of
        /// (primary key <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>) in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to store in the data store.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to store in the data store.</param>
        Task IDataStore.StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key Must have a value");
            }

            var serialized = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Serialize(value);

            _context.GoogleCredentials.Add(new()
            {
                Key = GenerateStoredKey(key),
                Credentials = serialized
            });
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return Task.Delay(0);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the given key. It deletes the <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/> row in
        /// <see cref="GoogleCredentials"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key to delete from the data store.</param>
        Task IDataStore.DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
            }

            try
            {
                var hold = _context.GoogleCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
                _context.GoogleCredentials.Remove(hold);
                _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to delete credentials");
            }

            return Task.Delay(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the stored value for the given key or <c>null</c> if the matching row (<see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>
        /// in <see cref="GoogleCredentials"/> doesn't exist.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type to retrieve.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="key">The key to retrieve from the data store.</param>
        /// <returns>The stored object.</returns>
        Task<T> IDataStore.GetAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
            }

            TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
            var user = GetUserByKey(GenerateStoredKey(key));
            if (user != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    tcs.SetResult(NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<T>(user.Credentials));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tcs.SetException(ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tcs.SetResult(default(T));
            }
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears all values in the data store. This method deletes all files in <see cref="GoogleCredentials"/>.
        /// </summary>
        Task IDataStore.ClearAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in _context.GoogleCredentials)
                {
                    _context.GoogleCredentials.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to clear credentials");
            }

            return Task.Delay(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if the user exists <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private GoogleCredentials GetUserByKey(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = _context.GoogleCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user != null)
                    return user;

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save the credentials.  If the user <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/> does not exists we insert it other wise we will do an update.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="serialized"></param>
        private void save(string key, string serialized)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = _context.GoogleCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    var hold = new GoogleCredentials { Key = key, Credentials = serialized };
                    _context.GoogleCredentials.Add(hold);
                }
                else
                {
                    var aUser = _context.GoogleCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
                    aUser.Credentials = serialized;
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Creates a unique stored key based on the key and the current project name.</summary>
        /// <param name="key">The object key.</param>
        public static string GenerateStoredKey(string key)
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name, key);
        }
    }
```

and then my google Credentials Model

```
public class GoogleCredentials
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(500)]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Credentials { get; set; }
    }
```

Still new to all this but this is what I have, I think I'm in the right direction from what I understand but maybe some one a little more knowledgeable can take a look and set me down the right path.

Comment: Thats a really good question. I wrote that a long time ago.  My guess would be something to identify the user you are storing the token for. your internal user id.   Why i didnt set it to use "user" like file datastore does i dont know.   If i can find some time tomorrow i will play with it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, . it is the only information I could find. I hope you get some time to mess with it if you do find a solution please let me know as I said it is my sticking point so cant move forward with anything on this part of the project . :)/

Comment: Have you had a look at the other ones [DatabaseDatastore.cs](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/a11851d51f13addd70264d01be1928bf)  I will check it in the morning.  I don't think i ever wrote a blog post on it.

Comment: No, I have not as mine uses EntityFramework Core so that is the only one I looked at. I will take a look and see if I can come up with something. thanks

Comment: I wrote a blog post on how Filedatastore works.  thats the default one if you dont supply your own.   [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)  It may give you an idea of how i created the other ones.

Comment: Thanks, for the input Ill have a go at that as well. Any further info you can give later will be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor takes a connection string.

```
  public static UserCredential InstalledCredential(string credFilePath, string[] scopes, string userName, string connectionString)
        {
            return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(credFilePath).Secrets,
                scopes,
                userName,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new EntityFrameworkDataStore(connectionString)).Result;
        }
```

## EntityFrameworkDataStore

```
internal sealed class EntityFrameworkDataStore : DbContext, IDataStore
{
    public DbSet<GoogleUserCredential> GoogleUserCredentials { get; set; }

    /// <summary>The string used to open the connection.</summary>
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new table in the data base if the Users table does not exist within the database used in the connectionstring.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionString">The string used to open the connection.</param>
    public EntityFrameworkDataStore(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the given value for the given key. It creates a new row in the database with the user id of
    /// (primary key <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>) in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to store in the data store.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to store in the data store.</param>
    Task IDataStore.StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
        }

        var serialized = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Serialize(value);
        Save(GenerateStoredKey(key), serialized);
        return Task.Delay(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes the given key. It deletes the <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/> row in
    /// <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key to delete from the data store.</param>
    Task IDataStore.DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
        }

        try
        {
            var hold = GoogleUserCredentials.Where(a => a.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
            GoogleUserCredentials.Remove(hold);
            SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to delete credentials", ex);
        }

        return Task.Delay(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the stored value for the given key or <c>null</c> if the matching row (<see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>
    /// in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/> doesn't exist.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to retrieve.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key to retrieve from the data store.</param>
    /// <returns>The stored object.</returns>
    Task<T> IDataStore.GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Key MUST have a value");
        }

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        var user = GetUserByKey(GenerateStoredKey(key));
        if (user != null)
        {
            try
            {
                tcs.SetResult(NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<T>(user.Credentials));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tcs.SetResult(default(T));
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears all values in the data store. This method deletes all files in <see cref="GoogleUserCredentials"/>.
    /// </summary>
    Task IDataStore.ClearAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in GoogleUserCredentials)
            {
                GoogleUserCredentials.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to clear credentials", ex);
        }

        return Task.Delay(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the user exists <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/>.
    /// </summary>
    private GoogleUserCredential GetUserByKey(string key)
    {
        try
        {
            return GoogleUserCredentials.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == key);
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Save the credentials.  If the user <see cref="GenerateStoredKey"/> does not exists we insert it other wise we will do an update.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="serialized"></param>
    private void Save(string key, string serialized)
    {
        var user = GoogleUserCredentials.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == key);
        if (user == null)
        {
            var hold = new GoogleUserCredential { Key = key, Credentials = serialized };
            GoogleUserCredentials.Add(hold);
        }
        else
        {
            var aUser = GoogleUserCredentials.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key == key);
            aUser.Credentials = serialized;
        }

        SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>Creates a unique stored key based on the key and the current project name.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">The object key.</param>
    public static string GenerateStoredKey(string key)
    {
        return $"{Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name}-{key}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this ... we have decided to save to a file.. now we are trying to figure out how to  get this all to work with our electron desktop app with a loopback address to get the window.

Comment: Love to hear how it goes.

Comment: So far not going well information is sparse hopefully inspiration will come and ill have something  thanks

Comment: @DalmTo is there anyway to capture the authorization link that is created with the Web Authorization Broker to put it in an electron window or should I user more of the google authentication desktop example where it queries a specific auth uri. IF so what is the V3 uri that I can use with google drive cause that is all I am getting the tokens/refresh tokens for. To list contents of a users drive and display that on my Vue front end. What kind of info is there that I am not finding for this issue ? or should i write a new SO question about this ?

Comment: I cant say i have tried  electron before, and im at a loss to understand what it is exactly.  As for the browser the consent screen should be opened on the default browser on the users machine.  a web view isnt going to work.    If this system is hosted and the user connects to it via a web server you should use a web app, if its run on the users machine then its an installed app.     Go with a new question and give me some background info.